# How to search through dynamodb and provide best result irrespective of 1 mb limit

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, search, amazon-dynamodb

I have been working on a project that uses dynamo db to store a list of posts.

Here are my goals:
Ability to post and update a post (done)
Ability for a user to search through a list of posts (done)

The problem lies in the 1 mb max for scan operations

When a user searches, I do a scan operation to grab every post, then i use an algorithm to rate the relevance of each post, then I sort it.

Originally, I thought that this would be enough… I just have to add a pagination feature so that people can see the next mb of data.

Here is the problem:

Let’s say that the first mb of data has posts with the scores of 78%, 56%, 12%, and a couple 1 or 2%.

Okay. This works, everything is displayed.

Then the user clicks on the next page.

What if the next mb of data has a post with 80% or 90%?

How would I check this? I need the 90% to be at the top, except it is in the next mb of data, and can’t be checked until the user clicks the next page (and it would be pretty bad if all the good results were on the last page)

I’ve heard of things like batchGetAllItems of something like that.. but I am a fan of the 1 mb limit as it speeds things up.

How would I go about this? Is there some searching feature within dynamodb I can use?

Comment: It's called Elasticsearch ;-)

Comment: @jarmod how do i port my data into elastic search?

Comment: If you need general-purpose search that can handle arbitrary queries, then DynamoDB will never work for you on its own. It's common in these scenarios to add an actual search engine, such as Elasticsearch or OpenSearch or even [sonic](https://github.com/valeriansaliou/sonic). You populate data into the search engine via DynamoDB Streams (example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-stream-elasticsearch)). Also investigate costs before going too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong DB.

I'd highly recommend going through the various AWS presentations on YouTube...

In particular here's a link to [The Iron Triangle of Purpose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwnNbLXN4vA&t=2530s) - PIE Theorem chapter of the AWS re:Invent 2018: Building with AWS Databases: Match Your Workload to the Right Database (DAT301) presentation.
[image]

DynamoDB provides IE - Infinite Scale and Efficiency.

But you need P - Pattern Flexibility.

You'll need to decide if you need PI or PE.

Comment: are there any options in the free tier?